# Publish a package on Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center, package-management, ppa

Recent, I uploaded a package on MyApps. After uploading finished, I received a notice:

> Thank you for submitting a gratis Free Software application through MyApps. At this time we are unable to process this request, as we are working on the implementation of a new app upload process.
>
> To get your software out to millions of Ubuntu users in the meantime, you can either use a Personal Package Archive to distribute your app for free, or you can define a price to charge for your app.

Can new app upload process finish? and my request will be process?

How can I use PPA to upload my package. My package is a .deb package.

Thank you!